# 70s-80s scary supernatural film; kids are introduced to a beautiful but evil woman, the floor in her building leads to another dimension

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

The film was either American or Canadian, horror or supernatural, from the late 70's or 80's.

Kids are introduced to a beautiful woman in charge with long dark hair. She welcomed them. The place is a building with the word "Spring" in its name. The woman was really sinister and evil, and the kids had to be rescued from her. The floor in the building opened to reveal a portal to another dimension.

It's appeared on TV a couple of times and I watched it as a kid.

Answer (score 11):

["Invitation to Hell"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087480/) (1984 TV movie)?

It starred Susan Lucci as a demonic woman who wanted everyone in town to join her country club, which was called 'Steaming Springs', and it was actually a gateway to Hell, or a dimension that looked like Hell? Susan Lucci does have long, black hair like you described and the star of the movie, Robert Urich, does descend into this other dimension in the final moments of this movie to rescue his family. Here is the entire movie from YouTube.